# Ad hoc distribution broken in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, ad-hoc-distribution

I apologize for this not being exactly a programming question

I have a few apps that I'm deploying internally in our org using ad-hoc distribution with Enterprise account. What worked in iOS6 now creates two icons: one a normal app icon and another one is a weird default icon that has the same name as the main app. Clicking on this icon does not do anything. See attached screenshot (it only has the gray icons). I can remove the app through conventional means (long press and then the "X" icon), but I can not remove the gray icons.

Does anybody know what are those, and how do I get rid of them?

[image: iOS7 fail]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The fastest way to get rid of these ghost or dead icons is to make a backup of your iDevice and then restore it.
I tried every hint i found with google and nothing helped but the restore. So my advice: Don't google anymore, just backup & restore ;-)

Answer (score 0):

yes, we see that too. often but not always. it definitely looks like a bug

as for getting rid: no really good way...
restart the device, rearrange, delete a few times and wait a few days. a combination of that did the trick for a few phones here

no real solution except for apple to fix it :D

Answer (score 0):

I found a reproducible way of causing this problem.
For me, it appears to be linked to the plist used for over the air distribution.
If you generate it through XCode/Archive/Enterprise Distribution, it works normally.
If you subsequently update the ipa, but keep the old plist, you will get this issue if you did one or more of the following:
1) change bundle identifier
2) changed the mobileprovision used to compile
3) changed the app version

Can anyone confirm? Or is this only happening to me?